# Custom maven plugin not found

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have this project

```
+ foo
   pom.xml
   + bar
     src/main/java/foo/mojo.java
     pom.xml
```

the second pom is:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>mojo</artifactId>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging> 
  <parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
  </parent>
  ....
</project>
```

The `mojo.java` is

```
public class Mojo extends AbstractMojo {
  public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException, MojoFailureException {
    System.out.print("Hi");
  }
}
```

Then I run `c:\workspace\foo\bar\mvn clean install` to install the mojo.

Problem:
If I run `c:\workspace\foo\bar\mvn foo.bar:mojo:1.0-SNAPSHOT:mojo` it says:

```
[ERROR] Plugin foo.bar:Mojo:1.0-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for foo.bar:Mojo:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact foo:bar:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT in repo.jenkins-ci.org (http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: have you check root/parent pom info like version (should be "1.0-SNAPSHOT") ?

Comment: yes i checked the root/parent pom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is not looking for **bar** because he cant even find **foo**.

Run

```
c:\workspace\foo\mvn clean install
instead of 
c:\workspace\foo\bar\mvn clean install
```

Do dont build bar, build foo! Foo will automatically build bar!

```
C:\workspace\foo>mvn foo.bar:mojo:1.0-SNAPSHOT:mojo
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] --- foo.bar:mojo:1.0-SNAPSHOT:mojo (default-cli) @ foo ---
Hi
[INFO] Finish.
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- foo.bar:mojo:1.0-SNAPSHOT:mojo (default-cli) @ foo ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] foo ................................................ SUCCESS [  0.014 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 08:30 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-10T16:51:18+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/838M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: BTW: if you have a local nexus who swallows the plugin, remember to put the nexus into the `<pluginRepository>` of your local `settings.xml`.